# UITableView: How to load an image only once then use it in all cells

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

I'm creating an app using the Twitter API and parsing with JSON and every time I load the image into the cells it's taking multiple images and everything runs slowly. How would I go on by getting the image once then put the same image into all cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TweetCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
NSDictionary *tweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


NSString *text = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];
NSString *time = [tweet objectForKey:@"created_at"];
time = [time stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" +0000 "withString:@"/"];


NSString *twitterImage = [[tweet objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"profile_image_url_https"];
NSString *completeImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", twitterImage];
NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: completeImage]];
imageLabel.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];


cell.textLabel.text = text;
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", time];
  }
return cell;
}
```

Looks like this right now but really laggy when I scroll.
http://gyazo.com/8ab8325f3921fdb7e4f0ea0107d389ac.png

Comment: Never do Internet access on the main thread. Search here for questions about lazy image loading. Or look at the Apple sample app "LazyTableImages". And to ensure you load once, save the image the first time you download it.

Comment: BTW - please stop using `stringWithFormat:` when you don't need it. Example: `cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", time];` should just be: `cell.detailTextLabel.text = time;`.

Comment: Could anyone give me a sample code of what I could do ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the problem is in these lines:

```
NSDictionary *tweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *twitterImage = [[tweet objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"profile_image_url_https"];
```

I believe that is getting a new copy of the image for each cell. Each indexPath.row is a new tweet, thus you are getting multiple twitterImage

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the same picture, load it before the table's loading in a class parameter (for example in the `viewDidLoad`) and always use this parameter.

If it's dynamic, load the image in the background using `performSelectorInBackground`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use cache for images. I hope this link helps you:

http://khanlou.com/2012/08/asynchronous-downloaded-images-with-caching/

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are facing is because you are downloading all the images on the main thread.

To solve this either :

1. Download images using a separate thread using NSOperationQueue.
   A good tutorial on the same : http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues
2. Use this class 'AsyncImageView'. I have used this and it works fine. So, instead of UIImageView you will need to use the class AsyncImageView and this library will manage the downloading for you asynchronously.
   https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView